# How to add a class to <td> tags in a GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

I need to add classes to td of a GridView.
I've found [renderTagAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#renderTagAttributes()-detail), but I can't find examples how to use it.
Could you explain me this function or offer me other option?

My gridview:

```php
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'name',
        'price',
        'quantity',
        'created_at',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete}',
        ]
    ],
]); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For example

```
[
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center']
],
```

contentOptions - for td cells, headerOptions - for th cells

Reference: [Yii2 Docs | Column classes in GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#column-classes)